# Basic Salary Array Converted to Total Salary Array

Tags: java

I've created this *Array* which holds Basic Salary

```
static String[] BASICSALARY = {"$8096","$7661","$2427","$8467","$9122"," "," "," "};
```

And I'm willing to calculate the Total Salary in a method and then print the Total Salary Beside the Basic.

```
 private static void CalTotalSalary() 
    {
        System.out.println(" ID\tEmployee Name\t\t Years of Expirence\tBasic Salary\t\tTotal Salary");
        int size = ID.length;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
             System.out.println(" " + ID[i] + "    " + FN[i] + " " + LN[i] + "\t\t " +
                    YEARSOFEXP[i] + "\t\t" +BASICSALARY[i] ); 

        }


    }
```

I have thought of simply making an Array and enter the values manually, But in fact, I need to do the Calculation inside the program. Otherwise this's not programming.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you just asking how to add numbers together?  Your first step would be to store numbers, not strings.  Then you can add numbers with the `+` operator, storing the result in its own variable.

Comment: What does it mean if your basic salary is a space?

Comment: It's for adding extra information from scanner

Comment: What I'm asking is... Let's say I've made a function for Calculating Total Salary (Basic Salary * %5/Year Increment), its inputs will be taken from the basic salary array.
How Can I Save these new values (Total Salary) in a new array in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to use `List` instead of plain Array. Its more flexibel and useful.

get your basicsalary into a List.

Use `List<String> operators =LISTENTRY.split("[0-9]+");` for each entry in your list. Parse them. Then add them together. Simple as that.
I dont want to post plain code, it doesnt help you learn. Just watch some basic List tutorials or read a beginners Javabook to get into it.

Greetings, David

Comment: So I should convert the BASICSALARY *Array* to List? That's it.

Comment: @A.Hazim you should only use Lists in your Code. Makes it more managable. Many operations and calculations can be done with Lists. They provide a large amount of features that may help you.

Comment: @A.Hazim thanks for the marked as answer.